# newline characters (\n \r) not being respected with OpenFL flash.text.TextField on JS target

Tags: haxe, openfl

If I create a flash.text.TextField using OpenFL for a JS target, none of my newline characters are showing up.  The textfield instead has one long string on a single line.

I've tried changing `.wordWrap` and `.multiline` but they do nothing to change this behavior.

haxe *3.1.3*
openfl-html5 *1.4.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the file respoinsible for this behaviour.](https://github.com/openfl/openfl-html5/blob/master/flash/text/TextField.hx) There is no handling of multiline property implemented currently, and no `"\n"` handling also. So your only options would be to either transform the texts yourself, or implement that handling(and probably file a pull request to also help others).

Talking about `"\r"`, I don't think it would or even *should* be implemented, because runtime system isn't the place to handle incorrect encodings.